# How to format date in devexpress and knockout.js and insert it in the database?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devexpress

In html I have a div with

```
"dxDateBox:{
          type: 'date',
          value: currentDate}"
```

In the javascript file, I have this observable:

```
currentDate: ko.observable(new Date())
```

When I insert it into database with

```
 chModel.currentDate()
```

it inserts this:

```
Wed May 03 2017 11:08:50 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
```

instead of this, which is how my date is displayed on the website

```
5/3/2017
```

How do I fix it? 
P.S: I want the date on my website to be the current date.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this`

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
document.getElementById("spDate").innerHTML=currentDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + currentDate.getDate() + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
```

```html
<span id="spDate"></span>
```

I added 1 number to month because javascript months are zero-based

Comment: I don't know how to write document.getElementById in knockout

Comment: Try this way : var d = new Date();
        currentDate: ko.observable(d.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear())

Comment: Define var d = new Date();  on the top of the script tag in your page
and use it in knockout . 

Is this still does not work : 

currentDate: ko.observable(new Date().getMonth() + 1 + "/" + new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear())

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() { 
    var date = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDay();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("dxDateBox").innerHTML =month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
```

This works for me in javascript